# How do keyword research/analysis software work [theoratically]?

Tags: theory, google-ads-api, keyword-search

I have seen a lot of keyword research/analysis applications, such as Market Samurai: Keyword Analysis Tool, and SEMRush keyword tool.

My question is how can they get stats about those keywords ? are they using google api to achieve that ?

I fail to see how can a software not connected to google search database get information about monthly searches, competition ...etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Search Volume**, **Paid Competition**, **CPC** data, most of these tools get it in one of three ways.

- They can get it directly from Google via the AdWords API (requires "[Standard Access](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/access-levels#standard_access)" and must meet [RMF requirements](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements)).
- Another way is to get it from a third-party who can pull data from Google updated monthly such as [GrepWords](http://www.grepwords.com/).
- Using their own models with various data sources from third parties, mixed possibly Google's statistics and other [click stream data](https://www.jumpshot.com/company/data/), and applying machine learning algorithms to make predictions that can even rival Google's own data.

For **Keyword Difficulty (KD)** or **Organic Competition** scores, all tools provide an **estimate** of how difficult it might be to rank high organically for a specific keyword. Tools will typically use a combination of techniques. Below is a short list of what they may include:

- Search Engine Result Pages (SERP) analysis
- Each keywords' SERP density analysis
- Analysis of competitors for each keyword
- Word difficulty and frequency
- Backlink and domain authority analysis of competitors
- *and many other indicators*

**A few tools** and where they get their **Search Volume** and **CPC** data:

- **[SEMRush](https://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/#phrase_all)** uses an **algorithm** to estimate their traffic (source: spoke with them at a conference in 2016).
- **[ahrefs](http://help.ahrefs.com/ahrefs-metrics/where-does-your-search-volume-data-for-keywords-come-from)** uses a **third party** to get **click stream data** and pairs it with **data from Google**
- **[MOZ](https://moz.com/explorer)** uses a **third party** to get their **Google data** and **click stream data** (source: spoke with team).
- **[KWFinder](https://kwfinder.com/alternative-to-keyword-planner.html)** reports that their **data is the same as Google** Keyword Planner.
- **[Twinword Ideas](https://www.twinword.com/ideas/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=howdokeywordresearchanalysissoftwarework)** **actually** gets their data **directly from Google** (source: I work there).

Comment: Thank you for you're detailed answer :).